# recharts add close button across each bar in MultiBarChart along Y-axis in order to close the bars

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, recharts

I need to add a cross button along each bar which is being displayed against Y-axis, which will be helpful for users to close the bars. I am following vertical layout, bar would be placed along Y-xis. I tried to add it using LabelList but not able to achieve it. Can someone suggest me how can this be achieved?

[image]

Comment: Can you share a code sandbox or codepen with your code so far?

Comment: Thanks, I found out the solution to my problem.It has been explained on recharts site link to the same is http://recharts.org/en-US/guide/customize.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you're trying to do is create a custom tickFormatter along the y-axis. You said you've tried to add the cross using LabelList - have you tried using tickFormatter to create a custom tick that can be displayed? I would personally play around with that until I got it showing up the way I wanted it.

Then, I would think of what I would need to do to get the bars to "close" when a user clicks on the cross icon.

Would I just do a display none? Would I use `Array.prototype.splice` to remove it at a specific index?

I would take a closer look at the Y-Axis documentation for recharts here ---> http://recharts.org/en-US/api/YAxis

and I would also suggest looking at the customized bar chart event to see how their onClick is being used ---> http://recharts.org/en-US/examples/BarChartWithCustomizedEvent

I think instead of using LabelList, you should try to use tickFormatter, because from what it seems with LabelList, it's meant to be used on a bar component ---> http://recharts.org/en-US/api/LabelList

While with tickFormatter, that would be affecting the ticks that are on the side of the chart and you could format it so the ticks don't show the numbers but it shows the cross icon as you mentioned and then create a custom tooltip to display the numbers.

I hope this wasn't too long and confusing and was somewhat helpful :)

Comment: Thanks, I found out the solution to my problem.It has been explained on recharts site,  link to the same is http://recharts.org/en-US/guide/customize.